# Why do players and some parent coaches tell the pitcher "you are only just a pitcher,you're not really a baseball player"?

Tags: baseball

I was very surprised by a comment from an assistant coach in charge of the pitchers. First night for my son in a new club, first night of trials for division 1. The group of pitchers were told "Pitchers are no body's, all you know how to do is pitch". Now the catchers say the same. Is there a real resentment towards pitchers? Some one has to do it. From what I have seen of this years World Series 2014 thank goodness for Madison Bumgarner. Should my son expect this as he goes further? He is in the U17's, is this normal?

Comment: The pitcher is probably the most important position on the team, so perhaps it is just the coach's (rather insensitive) way of making the other players not feel bad that they aren't a pitcher.

Comment: I don't know why anyone would say such a thing - even if it were true (which it's certainly not!).  Terrible thing for a coach to say.

Answer (score 5):

Speaking from experience, I think that it was probably misinterpreted.  Most position players often crack jokes and make fun of pitchers.  This is mostly in a joking and playful mindset on a team.

In college the pitchers will practice separately from the team except during a few drills.  Position players don't see all pitchers as capable athletes.  This certainly isn't true, but it is hard to compare lower levels to the Major Leagues or Madison Bumgarner because they are the best of the best.

There are certainly pitchers in high school and college that are only capable of being a pitcher, and not playing another position, while there are also great athletes that pitch and play a position too.

Usually those players that play a position and pitch aren't seen as P.O.'s (pitcher onlys), and they will receive treatment from others as a position player.

Basically if you are a P.O. you are viewed as a lower athlete on the team, or you would be playing a position/hitting.  Mostly in fun players will joke with pitchers that they are worthless, poor athletes, etc.  Pitchers often accept this joking and will be able to laugh with position players after a great (athletic) play, or coming up in a big situation.

College baseball is also a very "earn your stripes" culture.  Freshman will get treated like they aren't part of the team until they earn it with their performance.  Pitching is similar.  No one is making fun of the ace, but the mop-up bullpen underclassman is going to hear plenty.

I cannot speak to the pros, but I wouldn't be surprised if it was a similar culture.

Also I am not saying this is the way it should or shouldn't be.  This is just the way it is in college baseball (as of a year ago).

Comment: I agree that this is most likely a misinterpretation.  My first response was that the coach must be an a$$; but more likely it was taken out of context.  No coach would actually say that as the OP interpreted.